# How do I get Facebook to use a thumbnail picture from my Posterous post?

Tags: facebook, hyperlink, sharing, posterous

When I share a link on Facebook from Posterous, I would like it to use a thumbnail image from that post or even the YouTube video.

Is it possible to do this?

At the minute if I share a link e.g. http://www.dan.ag/the-brick-thief-a-lego-short-film it will use the image_src meta that Posterous has set.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to put your own image in the post (and even hide it in CSS) just put it near the top.

Then, when you share the post in the box on Facebook it should show the in the list of pics to associate your post with ...

I'm assuming you aren't using the API?

Comment: I thought it was that easy but if you try to share that link I mentioned above it doesn't.